# Passing dynamic array to struct in c++

Tags: dynamic, struct

In every example I saw that tries to use a dynamic size for an array in a struct uses global constants at some point. What I am trying to do is pass an integer variable that is decided by the user to a structure that I create storing an array of that size, thus dynamic. Obviously the code below doesn't work, but it gives you an idea of what I plan on accomplishing

```
struct Node {

    char input;     
        int playingBoard[size];
    Node* pNext;
};


int main(){

cout<<"enter board size"<<endl;
cin>>size;
int playingBoard[size];  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Node
{
    int countr;
    int playingBoard[];
};

int countr;
...
struct Node *p = malloc(offsetof(Node, playingBoard) + 
  countr* sizeof *p->playingBoard);
p->countr= countr;

...
```

or an independent dynamically-allocated array

```
struct Node
{
    int countr;
    int *playingBoard;
};


Node holder;
...
holder.playingBoard = 
  malloc(holder.countr * sizeof *holder.playingBoard);
```